# How to calculate precision-recall curves for semantic (image) segmentation?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-segmentation, precision-recall

I am performing semantic segmentation (with materials as classes) on images, and wish to calculate precision-recall curves of my accuracy. Currently, I calculate the true positives, false positives and false negatives for each class by summing the number of pixels for which ground truth and prediction agree with that class, for which only the prediction agrees, and for which only the ground truth agrees, respectively. Then I calculate precision and recall accordingly:

```
pixel_probs = np.array(pixel_probs) # shape (num_pixels), the classification certainty for each pixel
pixel_labels_pred, pixel_labels_gt = np.array(pixel_labels_pred).astype(bool), np.array(pixel_labels_gt).astype(bool) # shape (num_pixels, num_classes), one hot labels for each pixel
precision_mat, recall_mat = np.array([]).reshape(num_labels, 0), np.array([]).reshape(num_labels, 0) # stores the precision-recall pairs for each certainty threshold
prev_num_pixels = sum(pixel_probs > 0.0)
for threshold in sorted(thresholds):
    pixel_mask = pixel_probs > threshold
    if sum(pixel_mask) == prev_num_pixels: continue
    prev_num_pixels == sum(pixel_mask)
    pixel_labels_pred_msk = pixel_labels_pred[pixel_mask]
    pixel_labels_gt_msk = pixel_labels_gt[pixel_mask]
    tps = np.sum(np.logical_and(pixel_labels_gt_msk, pixel_labels_pred_msk), axis=0)
    fps = np.sum(np.logical_and(np.logical_not(pixel_labels_gt_msk), pixel_labels_pred_msk), axis=0)
    fns = np.sum(np.logical_and(pixel_labels_gt_msk, np.logical_not(pixel_labels_pred_msk)), axis=0)
    precisions = tps / (tps + fps)
    recalls = tps / (tps + fns)
    precision_mat = np.concatenate([precision_mat, np.expand_dims(precisions, axis=-1)], axis=-1)
    recall_mat = np.concatenate([recall_mat, np.expand_dims(recalls, axis=-1)], axis=-1)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(12, 5)
for label_index in range(precision_mat.shape[0]):
    r = recall_mat[label_index]
    p = precision_mat[label_index]
    sort_order = np.argsort(r)
    r = r[sort_order]
    p = p[sort_order]
    plt.plot(r, p, '-o', markersize=2, label=labels[label_index])
plt.title("Precision-recall curve")
plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=8.5, ncol=1, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
plt.xlabel('recall', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('precision', fontsize=12)
plt.savefig(dir + "test/pr_curves.png")
```

However, this produces some very strange looking graphs:

[image]

It is true that my segmentator is performing rather horribly, but I would at least expect the curves to follow more or less a downward slope.

Am I calculating my PR-curve correctly? Are there alternative ways of calculating such curves that I should consider? Is there perhaps a bug in my plotting code?